# How to apply style for notify.js alert message

Tags: javascript, notifyjs

I need to know how to apply `css` styles for a `notify.js` alert.

Here's my code -

```
$.notify({
  message: "Alert!"
}, {
  type: 'danger',
  animate: {
    enter: 'animated fadeInUp',
  },
  placement: {
    from: "top",
    align: "center"
  },
  offset: 20,
  spacing: 10,
  z_index: 1031,
});
```

I need to apply some styles for this.

Comment: `$.notify.addStyle()` is your friend. here, read the documentation: https://notifyjs.com

Answer (score 0):

```
$.notify({
  message: "Alert!"
}, {
  type: 'danger',
  animate: {
    enter: 'animated fadeInUp',
  },
  placement: {
    from: "top",
    align: "center"
  },
  offset: 20,
  spacing: 10,
  z_index: 1031,
  style: 'addClassName'
});
```

then a structure like this will be constructed in html for notifiy

```
<div class="notifyjs-addClassName-base notifyjs-addClassNamesuccess">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="title" data-notify-html="title">Would you like some Foo ?
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
         <button class="no">Cancel</button>
         <button class="yes" data-notify-text="button">Confirm</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and thereafter you can create 1 css filr as per your need and add css making this `.notifyjs-addClassName-base` as the base class

```
.notifyjs-addClassName-base{

}
```